# Swift iOS -How to Create A Property with Getter and Setter on Extension of UIViewController Class

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, properties, extension-methods, getter-setter

I know in Swift your not allowed to use properties inside extensions.

I have a property and several functions that I use throughout my app in several different classes. I want to extend the UIViewController class to include the property and functions. I know that you can't add properties to extensions in Swift. I tried a computed property but it wouldn't accept that either so I resorted to a getter and setter. It's accepting it but it's not working properly because the property isn't getting set.

**What I'm looking to do:**

I want to be able to call steps 4 and 5 in different classes instead of using this same code over and over. Steps 4 and 5 access the same property which is initialized from another function inside the class.

**Steps:**

I add the property with a getter/setter and 3 functions as extensions to the UIViewController class.

1. the property type is a UIView that gets initialized from a function inside the class.
2. the function contains a label, a localView (type uiview), and an activity indicator. This function adds the label and actInd as subViews to the localView and then returns the localView.
3. the property from step one gets initialized with return value from the function in step 2.
4. another function accesses the property and adds it as a subView to the UIViewController class
5. another function accesses the same property and removes it from the UIViewController class.

I tried to use a getter and setter but it's not working.

**Code:**

```
extension UIViewController{

   //step 1
   var stepOneSetView: UIView? {
           get  {
                return UIView()
           }set {
                return  self.stepOneSetView = stepTwoCreateViewWithLabelAndActInd()
           }
   }

   //step 2
   func stepTwoCreateViewWithLabelAndActInd() -> UIView{

        var localView = UIView()
        var actInd = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        var label = UILabel()

        //do whatever then add actInd and label to localView
        return localView
   }

   //step 3 is inside the setter of stepOneSetView

   //step 4
   func stepFourAddViewFromStepOneToViewController(){

        view.addSubview(stepOneCreateView!)
   }

   //step 5
   func stepFiveRemoveViewFromStepOneFromViewController(){

       stepOneCreateView!.removeFromSuperview()
   }
}
```

Now when I subclass the UIViewController class I can use functions step 4 and 5:

```
class BlaBlaBla: UIViewController{

   override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           self.stepFourAddViewFromStepOneToViewController()

           //some timer happens and then

           self.stepFiveRemoveViewFromStepOneFromViewController()
   }
}
```

Where am I going wrong at?

Comment: Have you considered subclassing `UIViewController`?

Comment: @TomHarrington thanks for the reply! what do you mean? Isn't that what I did at the bottom when I created the class BlaBlaBla:UIViewController

Comment: Yes, but you could create a subclass called something like `StepOneViewController` that has the `stepOneSetView` property, and then have `BlaBlaBla` subclass `StepOneViewController`.

Comment: @TomHarrington thanks again. I never knew you can do that? So your saying create a class named StepOneController:UIViewController, create a the property I need in it and then all the functions necessary to mutate and access it, and then create BlaBlaBla:StepOneController and BlaBlaBla will still have the same functionality as a UIViewController but now it will also have access to the custom property and methods from StepOneController?

Comment: If `BlaBlaBla` is a subclass of `StepOneViewController`, then yes. Inheritance can go as many levels as you need.

Comment: @TomHarrington I'll try it. I know about inheritance but I never saw anyone use it the way you did except for making custom classes. It never crossed my mind. I have a question. This is for Reachability, the code is in every class, that's why I want to add these as extensions so I can cut down my code. I have about 40 classes all UIViewController. I also have an UIViewController extension class with a bunch of diff methods. If I do it the way you suggest, that means I will have to change all 40 classes to :StepOneController. Should I do that or get it working in the UIViewController extension?